# How to compare 2 images to generate an alpha image

Tags: scripting, compositing-nodes, image

Let's say there's 2 rendering image A and B from same scene and same camera, how can I do this by compositor or script?

1. compare image A and B
2. turn the same part into an alpha and export to image C

I mark the boundary with a line for easy understanding, the real image don't have the boundary line.  Image C's boundary is same to the image B' (crop B's blank area)

It might be too complicated to understand, let me know if you had any question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open the Compositor add two Input->Image nodes with your images and the use the Converter->Math to perform the required calculation. Output can be to a Viewer or File Output node.

Comment: If you only have the two images, you could use *Color Key* to remove the blue cube. In case you are rendering the images, you could either use the object id pass or cryptomatte to get an accurate object mask.

Comment: I have many images for objects in the same scene, so the method need to be a pipeline.